Persistent Volumes using Docker Compose (Dokploy, Directus)
I'm relatively new to Docker and trying to learn self-hosting to host some small projects. I use a reasonably new PaaS tool called Dokploy to manage my containers.
I have been trying to run Directus (v10.13.1) using docker-compose, and everything works perfectly, except that my uploads folder empties after each deployment. I am missing some essential information here since I have tried to set persistent volumes for the data according to the documentation, but they empty themselves after each deployment.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:
version: "3"
services:

    # Init permission: This service is used to set the correct
    # permissions on the Directus directories during the build.
    # Otherwise, the Directus application will not be able to
    # write to the directories.
    init-permissions:
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "/scripts/set-permissions.sh"]
        volumes:
            - ./database:/directus/database
            - ./uploads:/directus/uploads
            - ./extensions:/directus/extensions
            - ./templates:/directus/templates
        networks:
            - dokploy-network

    # Database: This service is used to store the Directus data 
    # in a PostgreSQL database.
    database:
        image: postgres:16
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks:
            - dokploy-network
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER:      "directus"
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD:  "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            POSTGRES_DB:        "directus"

    # Cache: This service is used to store the Directus cache.
    # It is used to speed up the Directus application.
    cache:
        image: redis:6
        networks:
            - dokploy-network

    # Clear cache: This service clears the Directus application’s 
    # cache when updated.
    clear-cache:
        image: redis:6
        command: ["redis-cli", "FLUSHALL"]
        networks:
            - dokploy-network
        depends_on:
            - cache

    # Directus: This service is used to run the Directus application.
    directus:
        image: directus/directus:${DIRECTUS_VERSION}
        networks:
            - dokploy-network
        ports:
            - 8055:8055
        environment:
            SECRET:             "${DIRECTUS_KEY}"
            ADMIN_EMAIL:        "${ADMIN_EMAIL}"
            ADMIN_PASSWORD:     "${ADMIN_PASSWORD}"
            DB_CLIENT:          "pg"
            DB_HOST:            "database"
            DB_PORT:            "5432"
            DB_DATABASE:        "directus"
            DB_USER:            "directus"
            DB_PASSWORD:        "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            CACHE_ENABLED:      "true"
            CACHE_AUTO_PURGE:   "true"
            CACHE_STORE:        "redis"
            REDIS:              "redis://cache:6379"
            WEBSOCKETS_ENABLED: "true"
            PUBLIC_URL:         "https://${TRAFFIC_DOMAIN}"
        volumes:
            - ./database:/directus/database
            - ./uploads:/directus/uploads
            - ./extensions:/directus/extensions
            - ./templates:/directus/templates
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.directus-${TRAFFIC_HASH}.rule=Host(`${TRAFFIC_DOMAIN}`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.directus-${TRAFFIC_HASH}.entrypoints=websecure"
            - "traefik.http.routers.directus-${TRAFFIC_HASH}.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
            - "traefik.http.services.directus-${TRAFFIC_HASH}.loadbalancer.server.port=${TRAFFIC_PORT}"
            - "traefik.http.routers.directus-${TRAFFIC_HASH}-http.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
            - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
        depends_on:
            - init-permissions
            - cache
            - database
            - clear-cache

# Networks: This section is used to define the network that the
# services will use to communicate with each other.
networks:
    dokploy-network:
        external: true

# Volumes: This section is used to define the volumes that the
# services will use to store their data persistently.
volumes:
    directus:
    postgres_data:

Here is also my /scripts/set-permissions.sh used by busybox to give the correct permissions:
chown -R 1000:1000 /directus/uploads /directus/extensions /directus/database /directus/templates
chmod -R 755 /directus/uploads /directus/extensions /directus/database /directus/templates

Here is the default run command used by Dokploy:
(docker compose -p directus-e2be29 -f ./docker-compose.yml up -d --build --remove-orphans)


Can any more knowledgeable person guide me on the right track? I will try to answer all the questions the best I can. Thank you all in advance! Also please let me know if this question doesn't belong to this StackExchange community.

You may need to change these lines in your docker-compose.yml:
        volumes:
            - ./database:/directus/database
            - ./uploads:/directus/uploads
            - ./extensions:/directus/extensions
            - ./templates:/directus/templates

to
        volumes:
            - ../files/database:/directus/database
            - ../files/uploads:/directus/uploads
            - ../files/extensions:/directus/extensions
            - ../files/templates:/directus/templates


I ran into a similar issue when setting up volumes with Dokploy and docker-compose and missed the section where they show the preferred way to set up persistent volumes in their documentation
https://docs.dokploy.com/en/docs/core/docker-compose/overview#advanced
If you scroll down to the bottom of this page they say this:

Docker volumes are a way to persist data generated and used by Docker containers. They are particularly useful for maintaining data between container restarts or for sharing data among different containers.
To bind a volume to the host machine, you can use the following syntax in your docker-compose.yml file, but this way will clean up the volumes when a new deployment is made:
volumes:
  - "/folder:/path/in/container" ❌

It's recommended to use the ../files folder to ensure your data persists between deployments. For example:
volumes:
  - "../files/my-database:/var/lib/mysql" ✅
  - "../files/my-configs:/etc/my-app/config" ✅


